# how to post/submit form values on textbox focus out event in asp.net mvc2 with out Jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, textbox, blur, form-post, focusout

I have two text boxes using Html.TextboxFor() helper. When I type values in Textbox1 and click outside (moving out the cursor from the textbox), TextBox2 should be populated with TextBox2.

I am aware of that using Javascript/Jquery, fill the values, but i don't an option use any of the client side script.
So I have to post the form values to controller action method & fill Textbox1 values with TextBox2 using model object.

how to post/submit  form values on textbox focus out event in asp.net mvc2 with out Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to post/submit form values on textbox focus out event in asp.net mvc2 with out Jquery?

Perfectly impossible without javascript. You need to subscribe to the `onchange` event of the first textbox and then trigger the form submission (once again using javascript).

If you cannot use javascript, your only option is to have a submit button on the form that the will submit the form and the corresponding text values once the user clicks on it.